# Could not locate executable C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe in the hadoop binaries

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163390/java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-ha) but spark still comes up with error: "Could not locate executable C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe in the hadoop binaries". I have the right winutils.exe file (2.7.1) for the Spark version(2.1.0) on my Windows computer. The path variable points to C:\hadoop\bin which is where the winutils.exe is located. And I ran  winutils.exe chmod 777 -R C:\tmp\hive in the command window as Administrator.

Any more ideas other than switching to a Unix/Linux setup?

Comment: **Which** error? Is it about Winutils, about Native Libraries, about Derby database startup, about filesystem privileges, about missing JARs?

Comment: Sorry it's the error in the heading of the post: "Could not locate executable C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe in the hadoop binaries". I will edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Assuming that you downloaded not only `winutils.exe` but also the native libraries i.e. `hadoop.dll` and `hadoop.lib` (in the same dir), you don't need to set the PATH but only... in `conf\spark-env.sh` > `set HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop`; in  `conf\spark-defaults.conf` > `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions  -Djava.library.path=C:/hadoop/bin` *(side note, the Linux-style forward slash is safer that the Windows-style backslash when passing Java properties)*

Comment: Success! I know saying thanks is bad form here but I'm gonna be a jerk. Thanks Samson. I wonder why this step doesn't seem to be mentioned in any of the tutorials I've rummaged through?

Comment: Not even https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html ?? Note that setting the `PATH` env variable is a Windows-specific workaround for `java.library.path` (on Linux it would be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable)