# SPARK/pyspark - not running hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder

Tags: apache-spark, hive, installation, pyspark

I have a problem with running `pyspark` from `Windows command line`. I don't know what is causing the issue.
Spark-shell is running normally.

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:Java`, where I have installed JDK `java version "1.8.0_161"`

`SPARK_HOME` is set to `C:\Users\heyde\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark`, where I have installed it through pip in `Anaconda`

Also I have added `C:\Users\heyde\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\bin` and `C:Java\bin` to system `PATH`.

**Console**

[image]
[image]

**Spark-shell**

[image]

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645398/could-not-locate-executable-c-hadoop-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-hadoop-binaries