# "Failed to locate the winutils binary" yet my pyspark still works

Tags: python, windows, hadoop, pyspark

In Windows, when I start my pyspark shell, I am getting the error:

```
2019-04-20 08:11:34 ERROR Shell:397 - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

However, after that error my pyspark shell starts fine and I have no problems running pyspark and running code on it. However, I get this error every single time and I am not sure how to get rid of it.

I have my environmental variables set up properly (like many have suggested for this problem) and I have winutils.exe in the correct bin folder. (I also have winutils.exe and hadoop.dll in the respective bin folder of Hadoop).  I believe if these things were not set up, pyspark shell wouldn't even work.

For reference, my environmental variables are set up as:

- HADOOP_HOME: C:\hadoop
- SPARK_HOME: C:\Spark\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7
- In the Path I have put: C:\Spark\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7 and C:\hadoop\bin.

I have put the same variables for system variables (in addition to user variables).

Hadoop also works fine and starts (except for displaying the 50070 UI, while it displays the 8080 UI, though that may be a separate issue).

Could this simply be a cached error that won't go away? Any suggestions to get rid of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! The error does not show anymore. I simply made the following changes to these files: "conf\spark-env.sh > set HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop; in conf\spark-defaults.conf > spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Djava.library.path=C:/hadoop/bin"

As suggested by this user in their comment:

[Could not locate executable C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe in the hadoop binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645398/could-not-locate-executable-c-hadoop-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-hadoop-binaries?rq=1#comment78264274_45645398)

So in addition to having the proper winutils.exe in the /bin, your environmental variables set up as I wrote above, one must also make those additions to the files that I specified above. Then there should be no problem or error when running pyspark on locally on windows!